# Why do I get the error: "Gave up waiting for prefetcher after 300 seconds" when I do a reboot trace on Windows 10 (TH2) on an SSD Drive?

Tags: windows, trace, reboot, prefetch, xperf

I am trying to measure reboot performance using Windows Performance Toolkit (WPT). The systems I am facing an error on have Windows 10 Threshold 2 on an SSD Drive.

The command I use is:

```
xbootmgr -trace rebootCycle -noPrepReboot -postBootDelay 60
```

The error is as follows:
After the reboot the system waits for 60 seconds and then for the next 300 seconds I see "Waiting for prefetcher" on the screen. Then I get an error saying

```
"Gave up waiting for virtual prefetcher after 300 seconds. Could not wait for prefetcher."
```

I DO NOT see this error with the same version of the OS installed on a rotational drive (HDD) but only see it on SSD. I also ran the same command on an earlier version of the OS (Windows 10 RTM 240) and DID NOT face any issue.

I compared the following registry keys as well but there was no difference in the values for the keys:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SysMain

What is causing this error to occur specifically on SSD with Windows 10 TH2 but not on the other mentioned systems?

Comment: enable superfetch service again. It detects the SSD automatically and doesn't prefetch data from SSD (since Win8, changed from Win7).

Comment: The superfetch service is enabled (startup type: automatic) already and I'm still facing the issue.

Comment: have you tried WPRUI and selected here reboot under **Performance scenario**? do this work?

Comment: Yes WPRUI works. Thanks for the suggestion. But I'm still looking to resolve this issue for xbootmgr as I want to do this completely from the command line without any manual GUI interaction. I tried using WPR from the command line with the following command: wpr -start GeneralProfile -filemode -onoffscenario RebootCycle -onoffresultspath C:\reboot_Trace but I get an error : WPR.exe should be in the same path as WPRCLI.exe.

Error code: 0xc5600601

Comment: xperf/xbootmgr are dead and I doubt MS fixes anything. WPR.exe is included in Win10, so use the full path to the WPR.exe from the WPT folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe"

Comment: Yes I realized that silly mistake. I guess I will have to go ahead with WPR then instead of xbootmgr. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: so, the full path worked?

Comment: Yes. Changed the directory in command prompt to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\" and then ran the command successfully.

Comment: I've also asked MS about this issue and the Win10 inbox wpr.exe doesn't support on/off traces. They even expected an invalid argument error, but not this strange one.